# Высчитать подстроку в строке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Пишу сайт. И есть такая задача. Использую JQuery.

Есть такая строка

> Москва, Санкт Петербург, Санжейка, Кацапетовка, Ростов на Дону

1) Как высчитать

> Санкт Петербург

так чтобы получилось

> Москва, Санжейка, Кацапетовка, Ростов на Дону

2) Как высчитать

> Ростов на Дону

так чтобы получилось

> Москва, Санкт Петербург, Санжейка, Кацапетовка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "Москва, Санкт Петербург, Санжейка, Кацапетовка, Ростов на Дону";
var mass = str.split(", ");
var res = "";
mass.forEach(el => {
 if (el === "Санкт Петербург") return;
 res += el + ", ";
});
console.log(res);
```